# Cannot define public static void main (String[] args) in Eclipse EE

Tags: java, eclipse

basically i want to create a simple main class in Eclipse EE like this

```
package com.baileyproject;
public class Add {


    public static int addNumber(int n)
    {
        n += 1;
        return n;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(addNumber(5));
    }
}
```

Then it would show the error like:

> Error: Main method not found in class com.baileyproject.Add, please
>   define the main method as:    public static void main(String[] args)
>   or a JavaFX application class must extend
>   javafx.application.Application

It just happened with Eclipse EE (for Web Developer) only, if anyone knows how to fix this, i'd be very grateful.

Comment: Try cleaning the project?

Comment: what is your folder structure

Comment: @fdsa I did try, still got the error.

Comment: @akr   i created a Dynamic Web Project and inside Java Resources/src, i created this main class Add,java within the package

Comment: the problem is in the package.  if you remove the package then this code works.

Comment: @akr did try w/o package, still the default package is auto-generated when i created a new java file. If i delete the package, the file is deleted also.

Comment: I just created this class in Eclipse EE and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I created a dynamic web project and added your code to it.  Everything worked out well.  check if your project settings are correct.

[image]

Comment: thank you, it did work though i dont really know why, after trying to  run my project on a server (I'm using TomCat), the main class (Add.java) did give the result , before that it kept getting the error of no main class found :)

Comment: glad it worked !! Sometimes IDEs may behave unexpectedly.  I dont see any error in your code.